# How do I convert a Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime object to a string?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to write a simple php parser to grab Google calendar events and print the values.

```
$apiKey = "worworjdjdidjd";
$calendarID = "20c8uhdghs688s787h@group.calendar.google.com";
$optionalParams = array('maxResults' => '100', 'singleEvents' => 'True', 'orderBy' => 'startTime', 'timeMin' => $dateStart, 'timeMax' => $dateEnd);


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("CAL");
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarID, $optionalParams);


foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
   echo "getSummary ". $event->getSummary() . "<br />";
   echo "getStart ". $event->getStart() . "<br />";
}
```

the getStart function returns a Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime object. When I try to echo it to standard out I get and error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime could not be converted to string
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$event->getStart()->dateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more tricky than this since they are two type of events: Full day and with a start and end, so you have to fulfill both cases:

```
$dateStart = ($event->start->getDate() != '') ? $event->start->getDate() : $event->start->getDateTime();
$dateEnd = ($event->end->getDate() != '') ? $event->end->getDate() : $event->end->getDateTime();
$start = new DateTime($dateStart);
$end = new DateTime($dateEnd);
```

There at the end you have a nice DateTime object that you can format like you like:

```
$start->format("d.m.Y H:i");
// 20.12.2019 09:30
```